# Highcharts async drilldown (3 level) - drillup not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created an async drilldown(Treemap1 to Treemap2 to Line Chart) in highcharts. The data is obtained from server for each drilldown. The drilldown functionality is working as expected. The drill up from Treemap2 to Treemap1 is also working.

But when I try to drillup from Line chart to Treemap2, then I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null
```

During this drillup, I checked the series data and it's empty.

Here is the code for drilldown event:

```
drilldown(e){

    let drilldown_point = e.point;
    let chart = this;
    let current_level = 0;

    if(chart.drilldownLevels){
        current_level = chart.drilldownLevels.length;
    }

    //api call to get drill down data based on current level of drilldown
    if(current_level == 0){
        level_0_point_name = e.point.name;
        chart.showLoading('Loading ...');
        Api()
        .get('/dataFromServer')
        .then(response => {

            //get sub series data and set drilldown = true for 2nd  level drilldown
            let sub_series_data = response.data;
            sub_series_data.map(value => value.drilldown = true);

            //create series for sub treemap
            let sub_series = {
                type: 'treemap',
                data: sub_series_data,
            };

            //Update title and subtitle of subchart
            chart.update({
                title: {
                    text: "1st Level Drilldown"
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ""
                }

            });

            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(drilldown_point, sub_series);
            chart.applyDrilldown();
            chart.hideLoading();
        });
    }
    else if(current_level == 1){
        // console.log(this)
        level_1_point_name = e.point.name;
        chart.showLoading('Loading ...');
        Api()
        .get('/dataFromServer')
        .then(response => {

            //get sub series data and set drilldown = true for 2nd  level drilldown
            let sub_series_data = response.data;
            let x_axis_categories = sub_series_data.map(value => value.name)

            //create series for sub treemap
            let sub_series = {
                type: 'line',
                name: 'LineChart',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: sub_series_data,
            };

            //Update title and subtitle of subchart
            chart.update({
                title: {
                    text: "2nd Level Drilldown"
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ""
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Number'
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'X-axis title'
                    },
                    categories: x_axis_categories
                }

            });

            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(drilldown_point, sub_series);
            chart.applyDrilldown();
            chart.hideLoading();
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the fiddle link for the issue - https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav_neema/gkdoa9jr/7/

I have simplified the code for 2 levels. Drill down to any node and again press back button to drillup.

What can be the cause of this error?

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle with sample data?

Comment: Here is the fiddle link... https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav_neema/gkdoa9jr/7/

 Drilldown to any node and try clicking back button again to drillup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have an idea from [this](https://jsfiddle.net/200313/tb8mw9nv/11/) fiddle which I found on [here](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41369). You have to update the chat under drillup() event. Following is the sample code from the fiddle.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {
        console.log(this)
        var chart = this,
          drilldowns = chart.userOptions.drilldown.series,
          series = [];
        Highcharts.each(drilldowns, function(p, i) {
          if (p.id === e.point.name) {
            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, p);
          }
        });
        chart.applyDrilldown();
        chart.update({
          chart: {
            type: 'column'
          }
        })
      },
      drillup: function() {
        let chart = this;
        console.log(this)
        chart.update({
          chart: {
            type: 'treemap',
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
  
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },

  series: [{
    animation: false,
    type: "treemap",
    data: [{
      id: 'B',
      name: 'Bananas',
      color: "#ECE100"
    }, {
      name: 'Anne',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 3,
      drilldown: true
    }, {
      name: 'Rick',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 10,
      drilldown: 'BRickSales'
    }, {
      name: 'Peter',
      parent: 'B',
      value: 1

    }]
  }],

  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      name: 'Ricks quotes',
      id: 'Rick',
      type: 'column',
      data: [
        ['v11', 30],
        ['v8', 17],
        ['v9', 8],
        ['v10', 5],
        ['v7', 3]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Rick Calls',
      id: 'Rick',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        ['v11', 50],
        ['v8', 40],
        ['v9', 60],
        ['v10', 65],
        ['v7', 73]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Anne quotes',
      id: 'Anne',
      type: 'column',
      data: [
        ['v11', 2],
        ['v8', 7],
        ['v9', 3],
        ['v10', 5],
        ['v7', 3]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Anne Calls',
      id: 'Anne',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        ['v11', 50],
        ['v8', 40],
        ['v9', 60],
        ['v10', 65],
        ['v7', 73]
      ]
    }]
  },

});
```